# How to show userform, then hide, then show again without running the userform activate code again

Tags: excel, vba

I have a progress using a userform. I show the userform when a worksheet button is clicked. The button calls `startProgressIndicator()`

```
Sub startProgressIndicator()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

I have this as my userform code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Call myCode
End Sub
```

I then want to hide the progress bar and ask for user input. This occurs in `myCode`. I inlcude `UserForm1.Hide` in beginning of `myCode`.

After getting the user input, I want to show the progress indicator again.
I try `UserForm1.Show`, however, this just calls `myCode` all over again. I just want the same userform to be visible again.

I tried using `UserForm1.Visible = False`, but then I get this error

> Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an
>   Automation type not supported in Visual Basic

Comment: Use `UserForm_Initialize` rather than `UserForm_Activate`

Comment: @chrisneilsen When I use `UserForm_Initialize`, the progress bar does not update. The rest of the code only runs when I close the progress indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is to rewrite `myCode` to not include `.Hide`. Break `myCode` into logical chunks.

However, you should separate the logic from the display (see [Rubberduck UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) (*)). By doing so - you would only call `.Hide` from the form when you want to (e.g. on the 'Close' button click).

@ChrisNeilsen suggested using `_Initialize` and this will solve the immediate problem but will not set you up for better programming practices in the future. lso, if you decide to modify `myCode` you may get bugs that are harder to identify.

> @ChrisNeilsen: Use 'UserForm_Initialize' rather than 'UserForm_Activate'

(*) No disclaimer required, I am in no way affiliated with Rubberduck, but it does make good reading!

Comment: When I use UserForm_Initialize, the progress bar does not update. The rest of the code only runs when I close the progress indicator.

Comment: @Rish: This reinforces my opening statement about re-writing `myCode` and identifying the logical chunks. `myCode` seems to be hiding a lot of functionality that you want, but you are trying to do it all in one hit instead of when you want to do each chunk.